# Math Olympiad question easy? Ireland

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In the Irish 2000 math Olympiad question 1 paper 2( $Let:x,y \ge 0;  x+y = 2) $ prove that $2 \ge x^2y^2(x^2+y^2)$.  I find that you only need a basic proof for this equation, assuming that x and y are positive integers say x=y, then in order for x+y=2 to be true x=1 and y=1 by inputting the values 1 and 1, we return 2 which is satisfactory to the equation, therefore a proof that the equation is equal to 2, but it seemed to simple for a math Olympiad problem .

Comment: Even on the integers, you would need to consider $(0,2)$ and $(2,0)$ as well as $(1,1)$.  But I suspect you were expected to consider pairs of non-negative real numbers such as $(0.63,1.37)$

Comment: Most people won't use $x$ or $y$ for integers unless specified, "$x, y \geq 0$" here means they're non-negative reals.

Comment: (i) Why do you think you can assume that $x$ and $y$ are integers? (ii) Why do you think you can assume that $x=y$? All you have proved is that _there exist_ $x$ and $y$ such that $2\ge x^2y^2(x^2+y^2)$. You have to prove that it is true for $all$ (real) numbers $x$ and $y$ with $x+y=2$.

Comment: You have not proved anything. You showed that it is true for a particular value of $x$ and $y$, but you need to show that it is true for other values as well

Answer (score 4):

Note that you want to prove this result for all real numbers $x, y \geq 0$ with $x + y = 2$. The way to approach this problem is to use the Arithmetic Mean - Geometric Mean inequality:

For all $a, b \geq 0$ we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{a + b}{2} \geq \sqrt{ab}
\end{align*}

Using this here, we see
\begin{align*}
xy \leq \left (\frac{x + y}{2}\right )^2 = 1
\end{align*}
Hence, we have
\begin{align*}
x^2 y^2 \left (x^2 + y^2\right ) &\leq xy \left (x^2 + y^2\right )\\
&= \frac{1}{2} (2xy) \left (x^2 + y^2\right )\\
&\leq \frac{1}{2} \left (\frac{2xy + \left (x^2 + y^2\right )}{2}\right )^2 && \text{using AM-GM}\\
&= \frac{(x + y)^4}{8}\\
&= 2
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is certainly the cleanest way.A nother way to tackle the problem is to reduce it to a one variable inequality which in general is easier (through factoring for example). I will post it just to showcase the idea, you can write:

$$ x^2+y^2 = (x+y)^2 - 2xy = 4- 2xy $$

Hence if we set $t = xy$ we have that $t \leq 1 $ using AM-GM. Thus the inequality you want to prove is:

$$ t^2(4-2t) \leq 2 \iff t^2(2-t) \leq 1 \iff $$

$$ t^3 -2t^2 +1 \geq 0 \iff $$

$$ (t-1)(t-\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})(t-\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}) \geq 0 $$

And as $0 < t \leq 1 $ the first term and thesecond are negative and the third is positive the inequality is proved. For the equality case notice that only the first parenthesis can be $0$ , thus $xy=1$ which means that we have equality in AM-GM and $x=y=1$.

edit: Missed a square and messed the factoring, fixed.

Comment: I truly despise all of you